# skip an index under certain condition

Tags: while-loop

This code will run endlessly because of the while loop. I am trying to loop but only print the 'x_list' values where the 'g_list' value is unique. For example print the first value, then skip the second value, then print the third value and skip to the sixth value. Any suggestions on how to solve such a problem?

```
x_list = [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7]
g_list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
for k in range(0, 6):
    while g_list[k] =! g_list[k+1]:
        print(x_list[k])
```

There need to be a way to at some point stop the while loop after a certain amount of iterations but I am not sure how. I am relatively new to python so if you can guide me towards where i should be looking for, ill already really appreciate it.

Comment: Is this python?

Comment: Sorry, yes this is python or to be more specific ironpython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for k,x in enumerate(x_list):
    if g_list[k] not in g_list[:k]:
        print(x)
```

Uses `enumerate` to iterate over index and value.
Then creates a slice of `g_list` up to the current index, and checks if the corresponding value is in there.

Result:

```
3
5
7
```